# passing " from c# to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-3.5

I am trying to pass a script that contains the character " from c# to sql server using

```
thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is that the String is represented as \" instead of ": inside the string

```
thisCommand.CommandText = SQLscript; (string SQLScript)
```

How can I convert all the " characters to \" so that in sql I get only "?

Thanks in advice
reading the script:

```
StreamReader s = new StreamReader("export_script.sql");
this.SQLscript = s.ReadToEnd();
```

executing the script:

```
thisCommand.CommandText = SQLscript;
thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Inside the Script I have something like:

```
set @cmd = 'bcp "'+ @cmd_select + '" queryout "' + @partname + '" -c -S ' + @@SERVERNAME
```

you can see that I use " for bcp commands

Comment: Please show how you are doing it now (i.e. what's the text inside your `SQLscript`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# have a \ without \\ in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120129/c-sharp-have-a-without-in-a-string)

Comment: Never pass data in sql strings. Always use `SqlCommand` and `SqlParameter`. *(broken record...)*

Comment: If the slash \ is not in your `export_script.sql` file, it should not be in the `CommandText` either. Are you seeing the slash \ in the debugger?..

Comment: @atornblad can you please detail your answer?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, I see it

Comment: Ah. The backslash \ isn't really in the string! You only see it in the debugger, for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I solved the problem by adding

```
thisCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

It seams that the command is sent to SQL without \ in front of " if I use this type of command.

Answer (score 6):

Use SQL Parameters for that. It'll do the job for you - no need unescaping any dangerous characeters

Here's an example

```
        SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=Northwind;uid=sa;pwd=sa");
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        mySqlCommand.CommandText =
          "INSERT INTO Customers (" +
          "  CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName" +
          ") VALUES (" +
          "  @CustomerID, @CompanyName, @ContactName" +
          ")";
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5);
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40);
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ContactName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
        mySqlCommand.Parameters["@CustomerID"].Value = "J4COM";
        // The company name contains two double-quotes (") for demo purposes
        mySqlCommand.Parameters["@CompanyName"].Value = "J4 \"Company\"";
        mySqlCommand.Parameters["@ContactName"].IsNullable = true;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters["@ContactName"].Value = DBNull.Value;
        mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully added row to Customers table");

        mySqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Took the liberty of adding a couple of backslash characters to the example code, for example purposes only.
The main thing here is the principle of using commands and parameters properly. Never compose your own final sql, but use named parameters and let the MySql adapter do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [**Regex.Unescape**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx)-method can help you out? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent a double quote in a string literal, the escape sequence is two double quotes.

string myString = @"<xml attribute=""my attribute""/>";